# Javascript push() - undefined output

Tags: javascript, undefined, push

I currently try to safe data of different users in an array using the `push()` function.
Here is my current code:

```
function data()
{

    var information = [];
    var imgs = '';
    var percentage;

    var imgs = 'ABC';
    var percentage = '1';

    information.push({ imgs: imgs, chance: percentage });

    var imgs = 'DEF';
    var percentage = '2';

    information.push({ imgs: imgs, chance: percentage });

    console.log(information);

    information.forEach(function(deposit)
    {
        var deposit=deposit.imgs;
        var chance=deposit.chance;

        console.log(deposit);
        console.log(chance);
    });


}
```

This is the output of `console.log(information)`:

```
[ { imgs: 'ABC', chance: '1' }, { imgs: 'DEF', chance: '2' } ]
```

And this is the output of `information.forEach(function(deposit)`:

```
ABC
undefined
DEF
undefined
```

At that's my problem.
As you can see, it outputs the chance as `undefined` however it should output 1 and 2.
Anyone know why it do that and know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6):

On the next line, you reassign your deposit object:

```
var deposit=deposit.imgs;
```

Just change this variable name. Or assign chance before deposit.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! You may consider accepting the answer if it is the one you used :)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a value to the deposit variable which is also the parameter in your `forEach` function.

Therefore change `deposit` variable in `var deposit = deposit.imgs;` to any other random variable and also update the change in the log statement.
`console.log(**deposit**);`

Hope thats clear and I hope its solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because you declared 
`var deposit=deposit.imgs;` **deposit** here is another variable declaration.
Then the next line 
`var chance=deposit.chance;` this **deposit** is got from the `var deposit` above so it will result *undefined*. Just change `var deposit=deposit.imgs;` to another variable like `var images = deposit.imgs;`

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug inside the `forEach` of `information`. Basically your current code overwrite the `currentValue` of the `forEach` (to a string).

You could solve this issue by chaning the name of variable inside your `forEach` as shown below.

```js
function data() {
  var information = [];
  var imgs = '';
  var percentage;

  var imgs = 'ABC';
  var percentage = '1';

  information.push({
    imgs: imgs,
    chance: percentage
  });

  var imgs = 'DEF';
  var percentage = '2';

  information.push({
    imgs: imgs,
    chance: percentage
  });

  console.log(information);

  information.forEach(function(deposit) {
    // change name of variables
    var depositImgs = deposit.imgs;
    var depositChange = deposit.chance;

    console.log(depositImgs);
    console.log(depositChange);


  });
}
data();
```